# Branching strategy - for multiple release with gihub

Tags: github

I am working on the project where currently we have following three fixed branches

```
Develop - The code is deployed to development environment. It's a base branch for anyone who want to add new feature. 
Release - Deployed in QA environment, And QA can start testing on.  
Master -  Deployed to Production environment and available to clients.
```

And we have two more dynamic branches, feature and hotfix.

1. Anyone wants to start new development or bugfix, forks new `feature` from `develop` branch, then then creates a pull request.
2. once development is done it's testing in Development environment from develop branch it then creates a merge request for `release branch`
3. QA deploys the `release` branch on Test environment and start testing, once testing is done. it's merged to master and then deployed to production.

This all works well for most of the part. However, it has following problem

> Not every feature in QA (release branch) is tested and ready for deployment (merge to master) at the end of the release.  And so we are not sure how to create a pull request as it will select all the commits.

I am thinking `Github releases` might be a solution for this. I can create a new release with which ever feature is ready for deployment and then merge these releases with master branch.

However, what I am not sure is when to deploy to production, from releases or from master ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be following the standard **[Git Flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)**:

[image: Git Flow]

Instead of merging any feature to the `release` branch (from `develop`) after testing, what you'll want to do is make use of a 'release cut'. This is a dedicated point in time at which you decide you want to make a release. Features that are planned to be in this release are evaluated and tested, and the release is confirmed.

You'll want to **[`tag` your releases](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-releases)**, and optionally include any assets that are associated with that release for future reference. If it's a mobile app, this is a great place to include your `.apk` or `.ipa`. After the release cut has been made and tagged, you'll then want to **release the `release` branch to production**. Once that has been deployed out to production, you'll then want to merge `release` into both `master` and `develop`.

Under this approach, *every* `feature` branch will end up in `develop`, then `release` (with a corresponding `tag`), then `master`. If a feature is still in progress when the release cut is made, it simply doesn't make the cut! It will get added to the *next* release. This will give it adequate time for testing before it comes anywhere near `release`, let alone `master`. In this regard, `master` should be a mere representation of your last-known 'good state' -- a point at which you were happy to release to the public.

Also, note that `hotfixes` and `bugfixes` are two different things, and *neither* should branch from `develop`. Bugfixes should be made to the `release` branch itself, and `hotfixes` should be created from `master`, and merged back into both `master` and `develop`.